# Order of commuting elements $a$ and $b$ in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume $|a|=m$, $|b|=n$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)=1$.

Let $k,l$ be elements of $\Bbb Z$ such that $a^k$ is not equal to $e$.

Show that $a^k$ is not equal to $b^l$.

The hint provided tells us to use the result we previously proved, which is that if $|a|=n$ (finite), then $|a^k|=\frac{n}{\operatorname{gcd}(n,k)}$.

I have used the hint and proved that $|a^k|$ is not equal to $|b^l|$.

Not sure how to deduce $a^k$ is not equal to $b^l$ from there.

Hints and suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You've done all the work you need to do! Any element $x$ in a group has an order (which you're denoting $|x|$). Just giving an element a different name can't change its order. So, if $a^k=b^l$, then necessarily $|a^k|=|b^l|$; put another way, if $|a^k|\ne|b^l|$, then necessarily $a^k\ne b^l$.

Comment: @GregMartin I have forgotten that not q implies not p is equivalent to p implies q. Logic mistakes! thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! The word "[contrapositive](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gp2/lcontrap.htm)" is unwieldy, but sometimes remembering an unwieldy word can effectively help avoiding forgetting this in the future.